# Insert Query Not working

Tags: php, mysql

Hi i have a small query which takes data from one mysql database and inserts it into a duplicate table, the problem is i get the relevant data out of the database fine, but i can not seem to get it in to the new database, i have error reporting enabled, but i am not getting any errors.

Below is my code:

```
$dbhost                         = "";
$dbuser                         = "";
$dbpass                         = "";
$dbname                         = "";
$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass) or die ("Error connecting to  database");
mysql_select_db($dbname);
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ip_stats WHERE DATE(date) = CURDATE()") 
or die(mysql_error());  
// keeps getting the next row until there are no more to get
while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) {
    $id   = $row['id'];
    $date   = $row['date'];
    $ip   = $row['ip'];
    $hostname   = $row['hostname'];
    $company_name   = $row['company_name'];
    $address   = $row['address'];
    $descr   = $row['descr'];

    echo "$id - $date - $ip - $hostname - $company_name - $address - $descr"; 
    ?>
    <br />
    <?php
    $query = "INSERT INTO `ip_stats11` (`id`, `ip`, `date`, `hostname`, `company_name`, `address`, `descr`, `updated`)
      VALUES ('$id', '$ip', '$date', '$hostname', '$company_name', '$address', '$descr', 'yes')";
    echo "updated $ip"; ?><br /><?php
}
```

Comment: you forget to do the actual insert execution

Comment: Add this: mysql_query($query);

Comment: Where is the line which executes `$query`?

Comment: I think that using [INSERT ... SELECT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-select.html) would be better.

Comment: Why don't you use INSERT INTO ... SELECT ... ? Much faster! INSERT INTO `ip_stats11` (`id`, `ip`, `date`, `hostname`, `company_name`, `address`, `descr`, `updated`) SELECT id,ip,date,hostname,company_name,company_name,address,descr, 'yes' FROM ip_stats WHERE DATE(date) = CURRENT_DATE;

Comment: Thank you, can't believe i didn't notice that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@klijn is probably right that you forgot to execute the `INSERT` query.
However, I would advise to do this simpler and faster:

```
$result = mysql_query('
    INSERT INTO `ip_stats11` (
        `id`, `ip`, `date`, `hostname`, `company_name`, `address`, `descr`, `updated`
    )
    SELECT ip_stats.*, 'yes' 
    FROM   ip_stats 
    WHERE  DATE(date) = CURDATE()
');
```

One other thing - this construct:

```
WHERE  DATE(date) = CURDATE()
```

Might not be very efficient. You apply a function to the date column. If that is of the `DATE` datatype, you don't need that and you should leave it out. If it is a `DATETIME` and you want to truncate the time part, then doing it this way will make it impossible for mysql (and most other RDBMS-es too) to use any indexes on that column.

Here's a better way:

```
WHERE  `date` BETWEEN CURRENT_DATE
                  AND CURRENT_DATE + INTERVAL 1 DAY - INTERVAL 1 SECOND
```

The way this works is that `CURRENT_DATE` will be cast to a DATETIME (assuming the `date` column is a `DATETIME` or `TIMESTAMP`, and it will have a zero timepart, indicating the start of that day and the start of our BETWEEN...AND range. For the end of the range, we say: please use tomorrow:

```
CURRENT_DATE + INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

Which is in fact the first second of the 1 day later than current_date. This is not entirely correct, because `BETWEEN...AND...` uses inclusive range boundaries, so we substract one second with the `- MINUS 1 SECOND` to ensure we got the very last second of the day indicated by CURRENT_DATE.